# Change border of grid

Tags: extjs4

I have following code that I creating a grid

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: [
   { name: 'company' },
   { name: 'price', type: 'float' },
   { name: 'change', type: 'float' },
   { name: 'pctChange', type: 'float' }

],
    data: myData
});
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    renderTo: 'divGrid',
    columns: [
    {   text: 'Company',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'company'
    },
    {   text: 'Price',
        flex: 1, 
        dataIndex: 'price'
    },
    {   text: 'Change',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'change'
    },
    {   text: '% Change',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'pctChange'
    }],
        height: 250,
        width: '100%',
        title: 'Array Grid',
        renderTo: 'grid-example',
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        }
    });

});
```

I want to change color and width of border grid. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty you can set this config on any grid or really any component that draws a box:

```
style: 'border: solid Red 2px'
```

The more correct way is to create a css rule and set `cls:'myRedBorderRule`' in the config.

EDIT:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    renderTo: 'divGrid',
    style: 'border: solid Red 2px',
    .....
```

Answer (score 3):

ExtJS Grid Panel class provides you with parameters to define your custom styles. You can make use of the following class parameters :

- border
- bodyStyle
- bodyCls
- bodyBorder
- bodyPadding

You can use combination of these parameters to manipulate the grid's border and body styles. Refer to the docs for details of these parameters.

Comment: How can I use bodycls to change border ? Should I put it in configuration section ?

Answer (score 0):

Add below css to remove border

```
.x-panel-body .x-grid-item-container .x-grid-item {
        border: none;
    }
```